# Insertion sort implementation in scala

Tags: scala, insertion-sort

I'm trying out Scala and I want to see how one would implement insertion sort in scala with the following requirements:

1. Nested for loops
2. Array[Int] for input
3. If possible a way to modify the contents of the function in a call by reference way otherwise return an Array[Int]

If this isn't the Scala way of implementing insertion sort can you still provide code for the above and explain what is wrong with the approach.
edit:
This is an attempt using a while loop (doest work) and no it isn't a homework question, why the hostility?

```
def insert_sort(a:Array[Int]):Array[Int]={
for(i <- 0 until a.length)
{
  var j=i+1

  while(j>1&&a(j)<a(j-1)&&j<a.length)
  {
      var c=a(j)
      a(j)=a(j-1)
      a(j-1)=c
      j-=1
  }
}
return a
}
```

Comment: This _smells_ a lot like a homework question where you're asking us to do your homework for you. We'll usually _help_ people with homework but we aren't a code writing service.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post what code you have.  Is this homework?  We are not your personal coding service.  If you want people to write code for you, you should pay them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation given in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) fits your bill.  Here it is, copied, pasted, and converted to Scala syntax:

```
def insertionSort(a: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
  for (i <- 1 until a.length) {
    // A[ i ] is added in the sorted sequence A[0, .. i-1]
    // save A[i] to make a hole at index iHole
    val item = a(i)
    var iHole = i
    // keep moving the hole to next smaller index until A[iHole - 1] is <= item
    while (iHole > 0 && a(iHole - 1) > item) {
      // move hole to next smaller index
      a(iHole) = a(iHole - 1)
      iHole = iHole - 1
    }
    // put item in the hole
    a(iHole) = item
  }
  a
}
```

Answer (score 19):

This is what I came up with, which seems to be functional, generic, tail-recursive (`foldLeft` is tail-recursive)...:

```
def insertionSort[A](la: List[A])(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): List[A] = {
  def insert(la: List[A], a: A) = {
    val (h, t) = la.span(ord.lt(_, a))
    h ::: (a :: t)
  }

  la.foldLeft(List[A]()) {(acc, a) => insert(acc, a)}
}
```

Comment: This fails with @tailrec. And fails to finish sorting any big list. Gets stuck for ever. 31 seconds to sort 50,000 records.

Answer (score 6):

The most elegant insertion sort algorithm implementation that I'we  seen so far:

```
val rand = List(5,3,1,2)

def isort(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  if (xs.isEmpty) Nil
  else insert(xs.head, isort(xs.tail))

def insert(x: Int, xs: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  if (xs.isEmpty || x <= xs.head) x :: xs
  else xs.head :: insert(x, xs.tail)

isort(rand) // Produces List(1,2,3,5)
```

Algorithm implementation is taken from this great book: https://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_3ed

Answer (score 4):

My version of the insertion sort procedure is the following. It consists of two functions, `isort` and `insert` which have the following signatures:

- `isort(xs: List[int]) : List[int]`: Takes an input list of integers and outputs a list of integers.
- `insert(x: Int, xs: List[int]) : List[int]` Takes a sorted input list and an integer `x` and adds `x` to the right position in the list to maintain the invariant that the list is sorted. Example: `insert(3, [1, 2]) = [1, 2, 3]`

First let us code up the `insert` function.

1. If the list is empty, return a list of the integer to be added.
2. Otherwise, there are two possible cases. The head of the list is greater or equal to the given input integer, in which case we simply append the input integer to the beginning of the list and return it. The other case is when the input integer is greater than the head of the input list. In this case, we recursively insert the input integer into the tail of the list.

   ```
   def insert(x : Int, xs : List[Int]) : List[Int] = {

   xs match{
       case Nil => List(x)
       case y :: xs1 =>
           if(y >= x) x :: xs
           else y :: insert(x,  xs1)
    }

   }
   ```

The second function is `isort`, which takes an input list and sorts it. The algorithm is as follows:

1. If the input list is equal to `Nil`, return `Nil`.
2. Otherwise, recursively sort the tail of the list, and add the head at the right position in the (sorted) tail (using the `insert` procedure)

   ```
    def isort(xs : List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
     xs match{
       case Nil => Nil
       case x :: xs1 => insert(x, isort(xs1))

      }

    }
   ```

We can test this as `isort(List(1, 6, 4, -2, 5, 12))` and we get the correct expected output.

Answer (score 3):

Nested for loops are probably not the answer in Scala, whatever is the problem. They make sense in languages where for loops stand for "repeat until condition, changing this each iteration", which is *not* what for loops or for comprehensions are in Scala (a for comprehension is a for loop which yields something for each iteration).

In Scala, for loops and for comprehensions are iterations over the elements of a collection (or weirder things for non-collection monads), but for insertion sort you want to *find* a position, either swapping places up to that position, or inserting the element at that position. Finding stuff should not be done with for loops or for comprehensions.

Also, there's no pass-by-reference in Scala. And, in fact, `Array` is not even a Scala collection, but a Java thingy which has unique characteristics granted to it by the JVM that are not reproducible with classes, so it can't be replaced.

Answer (score 3):

here's another generic version of insertion sort:

```
  def less[T <: Comparable[T]](i: T, j: T) = i.compareTo(j) < 0

  def swap[T](xs: Array[T], i: Int, j: Int) { val tmp = xs(i); xs(i) = xs(j); xs(j) = tmp }

  def insertSort[T <: Comparable[T]](xs: Array[T]) {
    for { i <- 1 to xs.size
          j <- List.range(1, i).reverse
          if less(xs(j),xs(j - 1)) } swap(xs, j, j -1)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you need it for? 
If you just want a sorted Array I would prefer: `def sortArray(a: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = a.sortWith(_ < _)`.

Comment: if you're going to use the library's built-in sorting, you might as well do `a.sorted`

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning don't forget to add:

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._
```

This is my solution, using a list as an input

```
def insertionSortLoop(list :List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
      val intArray: Array[Int] = list.toArray
      for ( j <- 1 until intArray.length ) {
          breakable {
            for ( i <- (1 to j).reverse ) {
              if (intArray(i-1) < intArray(i)) {
                break
              } else {
                  val temp = intArray(i)
                  intArray(i) = intArray(i-1)
                  intArray(i-1) = temp
              }
            }
        }
      }
      intArray.toList
    }
```

I have the implementation here at [github](https://github.com/moxi/scala-algorithms/blob/master/sorting/InsertionSort.scala).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code sample written using foldLeft.

```
def insertionSort(input: List[Int]): List[Int] = {

  input.foldLeft(List[Int]())( (acc, element) => {

    val (firstHalf, secondHalf) = acc.span(_ < element)

    //inserting the element at the right place
    firstHalf ::: element :: secondHalf
  })
}
```

The example can be found in this [github](https://github.com/ChandraAddala/functional-programming-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/examples/NestedLoops.scala) repo.

Answer (score 0):

Even though, when coding Scala, I'm used to prefer functional programming style (via combinators or recursion) over imperative style (via variables and iterations), THIS TIME, for this specific problem, old school imperative nested loops result in simpler code for the reader. I don't think falling back to imperative style is a mistake for certain classes of problems (such as sorting algorithms which usually mutate a buffer of items passed as input rather than resulting to a new sorted collection)

Here it is my solution:

```scala
package bitspoke.algo

import scala.math.Ordered
import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer

abstract class Sorter[T <% Ordered[T]] {

  // algorithm provided by subclasses
  def sort(buffer : Buffer[T]) : Unit

  // check if the buffer is sorted
  def sorted(buffer : Buffer[T]) = buffer.isEmpty || buffer.view.zip(buffer.tail).forall { t => t._2 > t._1 }

  // swap elements in buffer
  def swap(buffer : Buffer[T], i:Int, j:Int) {
    val temp = buffer(i)
    buffer(i) = buffer(j)
    buffer(j) = temp
  }
}

class InsertionSorter[T <% Ordered[T]] extends Sorter[T] {
  def sort(buffer : Buffer[T]) : Unit = {
    for {
      i <-  1 until buffer.length
      j <-  i until 0 by -1
      if (buffer(j) < buffer(j - 1))
    }
    swap(buffer, j, j - 1)
  }
}
```

As you can see, rather than using `java.lang.Comparable`, I preferred `scala.math.Ordered` and Scala View Bounds rather than Upper Bounds. That's certainly works thanks to many Scala Implicit Conversions of primitive types to Rich Wrappers.

You can write a client program as follows:

```scala
import bitspoke.algo._
import scala.collection.mutable._

val sorter = new InsertionSorter[Int]
val buffer = ArrayBuffer(3, 0, 4, 2, 1)
sorter.sort(buffer)

assert(sorter.sorted(buffer))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Github link to Scala implementation](https://github.com/brodderickrodriguez/Scala-Sort-Methods-and-Data-Structures/blob/master/src/main/scala/sort/InsertionSort.scala)

Pseudo Code:

```
Algorithm Insertion-Sort-Descending(A)
    for j <- 2 to length[A]
        key <- A[j]                 // element we wish to insert
        i <- j - 1                  // position to the left side
        while i > 0 and A[i] < key  // while has not found correct position <-- difference between Ascending and Descending
            A[i + i] = A[i]         // right shift element
            i = i - 1               // decrement i
        A[i + 1] = key              // found position, place key
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers of [adijo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406064/insertion-sort-implementation-in-scala#answer-27960477) and [@RB_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406064/insertion-sort-implementation-in-scala#answer-44932945) are mostly right, given that you want an immutable implementation of insertion sort.

However those implementations, for lists bigger than around 50.000 entries will blow up the stack with StackOverflow error. This is due to the fact that the recursive methods used there are not @tailrec.

One possible solution is to use [CPS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9edE_4yvNOI&t=1666s) to make the method tailrec, as follows:

```scala
object Sort {
    def apply[A: Ordering](list: List[A]): List[A] = {
    
        @tailrec
        // In order to make this code tailrec, we are using CPS (continuation passing style)
        def insert(entry: A, list: List[A])(k: List[A] => List[A]): List[A] =
          list match {
            case Nil                       => k(List(entry))
            case head :: _ if entry < head => k(entry :: list)
            case head :: tail              => insert(entry, tail)(r => k(head :: r))
          }

        @tailrec
        def inner(sorted: List[A], rest: List[A]): List[A] =
          rest match {
            case Nil          => sorted
            case head :: tail => inner(insert(head, sorted)(identity), tail)
          }

        inner(Nil, list)
    }
}
```

Is worth noticing that an immutable implementation is always going to be slower than a mutable one.

From the [benchmark results](https://github.com/umbreak/algorithm#benchmarks) I've made, insertion sort performs around 2.5 times faster with a mutable implementation.