# Insertion sort not working in my code written in Scala

Tags: scala, insertion-sort

I am writing a function to perform insertion sort. While writing the code, I am getting the same list as output again.

```
def insertionSort(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] =
{
  if (xs.isEmpty) Nil
  else insert(xs.head, xs.tail)
}

def insert(x: Int, xs: List[Int]): List[Int] =
{
  if (xs.isEmpty || x <= xs.head) x :: xs
  else xs.head :: insert(x, xs.tail)
}
```

Can somebody please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insertion sort implementation in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406064/insertion-sort-implementation-in-scala)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are missing a small recursive call in your function. Please refer the code below.

```
def insertionSort(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] =
{
  if (xs.isEmpty) Nil
  else insert(xs.head, insertionSort(xs.tail))
}


def insert(x: Int, xs: List[Int]): List[Int] =
{
  if (xs.isEmpty || x <= xs.head) x :: xs
  else xs.head :: insert(x, xs.tail)
}
```

I guess that should work now.

Comment: Something like `/* HERE ---> */ insertionSort(xs.tail) /* <--- HERE */` would have worked ;)

Comment: Anyways. I have removed it completely @AndreyTyukin